# Mapas de xamarin forms no funcionan

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms

He seguido todos los pasos de la documentación de microsoft: **https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/map**
para implementar mapas como los de google maps en xamarin forms 
Tengo mi manifest de esta forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:label="$safeprojectname$">
        <!-- Put your Google Maps V2 API Key here. -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="xxxxx" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
```

y el content page con el mapa:

```
<maps:Map>
    <x:Arguments>
        <maps:MapSpan>
            <x:Arguments>
                <maps:Position>
                    <x:Arguments>
                        <x:Double>36.9628066</x:Double>
                        <x:Double>-122.0194722</x:Double>
                    </x:Arguments>
                </maps:Position>
                <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
                <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
            </x:Arguments>
        </maps:MapSpan>
    </x:Arguments>
</maps:Map>
```

Sin embargo al ejecutar la app se abre el mapa en blanco y unos segundos después se abre la aplicación de google maps lo cual no es la idea. La idea es controlar el mapa en el content page, si se abre la ruta en la aplicación de google maps no tengo como controlar la información. Como puedo hacer para que al ejecutar la app no se abra la aplicación de google maps y en lugar de eso se pinte la ruta en el mapa de xamarin forms???????????

Comment: Te esta faltando una declaracion que tenias en otro mapa. puede ser? que debe ir en el manifiest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasaba era que solo instale los Maps en el proyecto de net standard. Tenía que instalarlo en el proyecto de Android para que funcionara!!!!